# Populating aspnet_Profile table via TSQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to bulk load the aspnet members via TSQL from CSV File or Database sources. I'm happy with any other options i.e. net application or ssis packages.

The problem I'm facing is that each members have a their own profile as blow:

> 1. First Name
> 2. Last Name
> 3. Mobile
> 4. Company Add .... etc.

Looks like aspnet profile is stored as

> PropertyNames and PropertyValues

in backend aspnet_profile table.

Could anyone please suggest me how I can load the employee data and their profile on to aspnet membership database?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old thread, but how did you fill the values for `PropertyValueBinary` column? I have also left a comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming your problem is how to represent profile values correctly, here's how it's actually being stored in DB:

**aspnet_Profile.PropertyNames** contains profile variable names, corresponding storage descriptor and value length as follows: 
[VariableName]:[Storage]:[Start]:[Length]:[VariableName] ...
where

- [VariableName] - your profile variable name
- [Storage] - one char. B for Binary, S for String
- [Start] - value start position in storage string or byte array
- [Length] - value length

*Example*: Test1:S:0:10:Test2:B:0:100:Test3:S:10:5:TestDate:S:15:95

**aspnet_Profile.ProfileValuesString** contains profile values concatened one by one with no delimiters or anything else. To generate this column value you don't actually have to measure lenghts of values. To read from there you obviously have to.
Note: DateTime values are being wrapped into XML when serialized to PropertyValuesString.

*Example*: TestStringABCDE<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <dateTime>2011-07-29T10:00:28.1603073+04:00</dateTime>

**aspnet_Profile.ProfileValuesBinary** is pretty much the same as previous one. Except it's binary

So, having that said, your scenaro would be to get your csv data into a temp table in DB, then run a script over it to generate PropertyNames (most complex part here) and PropertyValuesString (easiest part). That's it.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old thread, but any idea how to set values for `PropertyValueBinary`? How to generate that `binary` part?

Comment: Generating the PropertyValueBinary field is just an array of binaryserialized objects.  The data in here needs to stay in sync with the PropertyNames definitions, such that the start and length need to be updated whenever data in the PropertyValueBinary gets updated.

If you are using C# to create your data to load into these tables, then using a BinaryFormatter() would be a class that could help you.